# Is a university 'coop' degree title worth the money?

Tags: internship

My university charges us $500/semester (three times a year) for 'co-op fee.'

For this money, all the school does is help you format your resume and give basic tips on how to do well in an interview. They also find jobs related to our program and forward them to us, however, they don't guarantee you get a job either.

These are all things I can do by myself. I can save myself $1500 a year, fix my own resume, and easily find the co-op job postings that my school provides on the internet.

Did I mention that co-op 'lectures' where you learn basic interview and resume skills are held every other week at 7 in the morning on a Saturday?

I am thinking about dropping co-op name from my degree as it seems like a huge waste of time and money at this point. The only drawback is that I lose the 'Co-op' title from my degree name. I will still apply to jobs on semesters I have off and work for the experience, however, my university will not be involved.

From a workplace perspective, is there a significant loss in my potential of getting hired if I drop the 'co-op' name from my degree?

So basically,

`BScH Computer Science [Co-op]`

vs

`BScH Computer Science`

Comment: I have never seen a degree with " 'co-op' " written anywhere on it.  Hell, getting my school to add completed minors to the degree was a two year battle.

Comment: I'm not from Canada (it appears you are), but I have also never heard of "co-op" being added to a degree title. If I saw it, I would simply ignore it.

Comment: I've never heard of "co-op" either.  It kind of just seems like an excuse for them to make an extra 1.5Gs.  I think you'd be fine to drop it.

Comment: How many of these do you have to buy to get the designation? It seems like if you're consistently getting coop positions along the way, it's worth it.

Comment: @JeffO to get the `co-op` title I need to finish 4 work terms (4 months or longer). The university does provide job positions available during the work term but that's about it.

Comment: For those not familiar with the term co-op, in Canadian universities, it refers to something akin to internship. The co-op placements are arranged by the university, although the students still have to interview for them. The work is evaluated by the employer and reported to the university. The universities have co-op offices that arrange the positions and manage the reporting. Employers often view participation as "good corporate citizenship" and co-op students are normally paid for their work.

Comment: A good coop experience can certainly be helpful. I've never heard of putting it on the _degree_ except as a subcategory of the course of study, and that only when it was a particularly pointedness and structured experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Long run the "Co-op" designation doesn't add much value.  The only point it comes into play is getting your first industry job.

The real value to the program is specific co-op experience.  Many employers will have term positions coinciding with the school semester that are specifically for co-op students.  Being in this program opens doors to student specific openings that you may not have outside of it.  My company hires 4-6 co-op engineering students each year and most of our entry level engineering hires come from this group.  I know that anyone applying for one of these positions who was not in the co-op program would immediately go in the "No" pile.

Comment: `I know that anyone applying for one of these positions who was not in the co-op program would immediately go in the "No" pile.` That clearly answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Another good one is `Whenever I get a stack of resumes, I throw the top half into the garbage. I don't want unlucky people working for me.`

Comment: @zymus - priceless! Myles, your comment is one way of filtering candidates, but realistically, it doesn't mean that non-co-op students might not have some work experience, or be worse suited for the job.

Comment: @AndreiROM Definitely there are some non-co-op students who would be better suited, however we specifically make short term introductory engineering positions that coincide with the university semester for recruiting co-op students specifically.  While this isn't the case for all companies it is common in my industry.

Comment: Co-op positions also can come with government funding, so hiring a non-co-op means the company just lost a chunk of cash.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes. Very empathically, Yes**.

The experience of actually going out and gaining work experience is ***priceless*** when you're competing for jobs with hundreds, if not thousands of other applicants at the end of your program.

Mind you, getting a co-op when you have no work experience in the field can be a chore - after all, every other student is a competitor, and some have already completed a co-op or two, so they have an edge.

But, assuming you're successful in securing one at each stage that you're offered the opportunity you could end up working at 2 or 3 different companies during your time at school.

Not only do they typically pay better than any minimum wage job, but you're also getting a feel for different kinds of environments, experiencing a professional workplace, and learning new things.

Furthermore, impress a manager and you could line up part-time employment during the school year, a good reference for later in your career, or a job when you finish school.

It's not just win-win, it's win-*win*-***win***.

As for why going through your school is worth it(in my experience):

Your school has a reputation in the industry. Companies approach them when they have co-op positions available and advertise on the school's website(not typically open to all students, only co-op ones). These resources become available to you, so hunting a job down becomes a much easier process.

Schools also typically enforce a minimum wage (for us it was $14/hr) and their counsellors checked up on us part way through the 4 month term to make sure that the employer was treating us well, etc. (if found lacking an employer is blacklisted and removed from their list of potential employers, which helps future students). All in all, worth it IMO.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand the importance of internships and coop but I was wondering if it's worth it to pay the university for their help. I could just as easily find jobs on my own and save myself $1500 a year.

Comment: @ishanM - the problem with going off on your own is that you can't work during the school semester (except part time). Signing up for co-op means you get a lot more flexibility from the point of view.

Comment: If I drop coop, I still have 4 months of summer holidays where I can find a 4 month internship so I don't have to work during school semesters!

Comment: @ishanm - up to you, of course. I found my own co-op experience to be very valuable.

Comment: @ishanm Keep in mind, many of the good companies will only hire coops for those 4 months of summer holidays. I am speaking as a software engineer in Vancouver, familiar with these programs and the employers who support them.

Answer (score 3):

**YES. YES. YES.**

I am currently a student interning, and my friends who are in co-op have far better paying, well known companies giving them interviews. That $500 is worth it for sure.

In my case, I had 3 total interviews for this term and 1 offer. They had from 10-20 interview and several offers. Co-op work experience will give you a leg up when you graduate. It also gives you a back-up choice when you graduate, if they have given you a verbal offer.

Folks who have no experience are at a massive disadvantage compared to those who do through co-op. It shows that you have work experience, are trained to some degree for your career and able to work in a professional environment.